# Asynchronous shell commands with screen

Tags: linux, shell, ant

I'm trying to use ant+scp to execute a script on a remote server.

The script on the remote server is pretty simple, it starts a game server written in java:

game_server.sh:

```
java -Xms500M -Xmx500M -jar game.jar
```

ant build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project default="restart_game_server" name="server"> 
    <target name="restart_game_server"> 
        <sshexec host="x.x.x.x" username="root" password="xxx" command="cd xxx; ./game_server.sh" trust="true" />
    </target>
</project>
```

When I run command "ant" in terminal (mac os) the game_server.sh on the remote server is executed  successfully but the problem is:

the "ant" command is blocked since the "game_server.sh" will never return.

I tried to solve this problem by starting the "game_server" in a "screen" but I can not figure out how to do this in a shell script, I tried something like:

```
# kill the game sever first
fuser -k -n tcp 9988
# resume the last screen or start a new one
screen -R
# move to the folder where the script is located
cd xxxx
# run script
./game_server.sh
```

But I don't know how to exit the screen using shell command instead of keyboard (c + a + d)

Any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks :)

EDIT:

Tried using the "&" way but still get blocked.

Here is the ant command output,  you can see how it is blocked:

```
root: ant
Buildfile: build.xml

restart_game_server:
  [sshexec] Connecting to x.x.x.x.x:22
  [sshexec] cmd : fuser -k -n tcp 9988; cd xxxxx; ./game_server.sh &
  [sshexec] 9988/tcp:         
  [sshexec]  12729
  [sshexec]   
  [sshexec] game sever log
  [sshexec] game sever log
  [sshexec] game sever log
  [sshexec] game sever log
  [sshexec] game sever log
  [sshexec] game sever log
  .......
  BLOCKED !!!!!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try running the game_server.sh in the background like this without using screen at all:

```
./game_server.sh &
```

or, you can try changing your build.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project default="restart_game_server" name="server"> 
    <target name="restart_game_server"> 
        <sshexec host="x.x.x.x" username="root" password="xxx" command="cd xxx; ./game_server.sh &" trust="true" />
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I have tired using "&" and the server is started in the background successfully but the problem is the "ant" command won't return and was block by the "game_server.sh" output ...

Comment: nevermind my other comment, I removed it. The issue must be something else. If I have any other answers I will help, good luck :)

Comment: actually what if the problem is in your build.xml? try changing the command in build.xml maybe?!?!         
<sshexec host="x.x.x.x" username="root" password="xxx" command="cd xxx; ./game_server.sh &" trust="true" />

Comment: Adding the & to the build.xml cause an error: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.

Comment: try: java -Xms500M -Xmx500M -jar game.jar &

Answer (score 0):

Use `screen -d -m` to run the screen in detached mode.

See the [man page](http://ss64.com/bash/screen.html) for more details.